# Взаимодействие с MySQL (ubuntu 18.04.1) и python (Win 10)

Tags: python-3.x, mysql, ubuntu, windows-10, pymysql

Есть задача, заключающаяся в загрузке данных, введенными пользователем в приложении, написанном на питоне и запущенном на винде от 7 и выше, в MySQL, который стоит на личном сервере под управлением ubuntu 18.04.1. На последнем установил MySQL, настроил, добавил пользователя, тестовую базу данных, в ней таблицу. Через netstat проверил, что sql слушает 3306 порт, systemcl status говорит, что mysql работает.  Кроме того, указал серверу статичный ip 129.168.1.14. И сервер, и пк подключены к одной сети ( пк, сервер -- > свич -- > роутер )

Проблема в том, что я не могу подключиться по указанным данным. Использую pymysql. Код ниже:

```
from pymysql import *

db_name = ''

try:
    connection = connect(
        host = '127.0.0.1',
        user = 'GSP_main',
        password = 'THERE_WAS_A_PASSWORD',
        database = 'tests_db',
        charset='utf8mb4',
        cursorclass = cursors.DictCursor
        )
    print('connection established')


    try:
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        
    finally:
        connection.close()

except Error as e:
    print(e)
```

```
(2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' ([WinError 10061] Подключение не установлено, т.к. конечный компьютер отверг запрос на подключение)")
```

Не могу понять, что не так и почему выдает такую ошибку, если все данные совпадают.

Comment: Если у сервера ip-адрес 129.168.1.14, то наверное и подключаться надо именно к ip-адресу 129.168.1.14, а не к 127.0.0.1?

Comment: (а ещё что-то я подозреваю, что вы опечатались в числе 192)

Comment: @andreymal , Вы правы, это лишь опечатка. Проблема также в том, что я пытался подключаться 3-мя способами - localhost; 127.0.0.1; 192.168.1.14. Все попытки были неудачными

Comment: А со 192.168.1.14 какая конкретно ошибка? Не стоит ли на убунте какой-нибудь межсетевой экран, который запрещает подключения извне? Слушается ли 3306 порт на всех нужных адресах (0.0.0.0) или, может быть, только на 127.0.0.1 (опция bind-address в настройках mysql)?

Comment: @andreymal , Насчет экранов - без понятия. Убунта голая стоит, только xfce сверху. С экранами не шаманил ничего. Сам я пользователь линукса очень и очень посредственный, так что прошу поконкретнее про проверку прослушивания порта на всех адресах.

Comment: Поконкретнее — в настройках mysql в опции bind-address должен быть прописан этот самый 0.0.0.0

Comment: "Вы можете отредактировать файл /etc/mysql/my.cnf для настройки основных параметров - файл журнала, номер порта и пр. Например, чтобы настроить MySQL на ожидание подключений от компьютеров в сети, измените параметр bind-address на IP адрес сервера:

bind-address            = 192.168.0.5
Замените 192.168.0.5 на реальное значение адреса вашего сервера.
После изменений в /etc/mysql/my.cnf сервис MySQL нужно перезагрузить:

sudo service mysql restart".         Оно?

Comment: Подключиться к бд я смог. Для этого залез в конфигурационный файл, прописал туда айпи, установленный мной, ребутнул mysql и пришлось вручную дать разрешение пользователю на подключение ( пришлось прописать конкретный айпи в mysql ). Есть вариант как-то сделать так, чтобы пользователь с любого айпи зайти мог?